# UWP : How to use System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection of WPF in UWP?

Tags: uwp

This code to rotate InkStroke in this [WPF doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-rotate-ink) :

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StrokeCollection copiedStrokes = inkCanvas1.Strokes.Clone();
        Matrix rotatingMatrix = new Matrix();
        double canvasLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(inkCanvas1);
        double canvasTop = Canvas.GetTop(inkCanvas1);
        Point rotatePoint = new Point(canvas1.Width / 2, canvas1.Height / 2);

        rotatingMatrix.RotateAt(90, rotatePoint.X, rotatePoint.Y);
        copiedStrokes.Transform(rotatingMatrix, false);
        inkPresenter1.Strokes = copiedStrokes;

    }
```

How can I use the class **StrokeCollection** and **Matrix** in UWP? They can not be resolve.

Comment: Did you look in the `Windows.UI.Input.Inking` namespace? The APIs might be slightly different but should be equivalent I think.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I find no class which can rotate InkStroke. Can you help me to reveal it? Please

Comment: [`InkStroke` has a `PointTransform` property on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstroke#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStroke_PointTransform). Does that not work?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I had used it before but it make program stop. So I thought that I was using wrong way. OK I understand now and I will study more about it.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT You have pointed out the crux of the matter. Could you convert your comment into an answer for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var strokesFromCanvas = inkCanvas1.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();

        var copiedStrokes = new List<InkStroke>();
        foreach (var stroke in strokesFromCanvas)
            copiedStrokes.Add(stroke.Clone());

        var bounds = inkCanvas1.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.BoundingRect;
        var centerX = Convert.ToSingle(bounds.X + bounds.Width / 2);
        var centerY = Convert.ToSingle(bounds.Y + bounds.Height / 2);
        var centerPoint = new System.Numerics.Vector2(centerX, centerY);
        var angle = Convert.ToSingle(Math.PI / 2);
        var rotatingMatrix = System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(angle, centerPoint);

        foreach (var stroke in copiedStrokes)
        {
            stroke.PointTransform = rotatingMatrix;
        }

        inkCanvas1.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.Clear();
        inkCanvas1.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.AddStrokes(copiedStrokes);
    }
```